# Форматирование даты в датасете

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

Всем привет! Суть вопроса - есть датафрэйм с датой следующего вида - **2017-05-08 21:46:36+00:00**. Для удобства работы надо переформатировать в вид - yyyy-mm-dd, т.е. убрать время.

```
data = pd.read_csv('ap-northeast-1.csv', parse_dates=['2017-05-08 21:46:36+00:00'], dayfirst=False)
data.columns = ['Date', 'Architecture', 'OS', 'Office', 'price']
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
```

Столбцы имеют следующие форматы:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 393567 entries, 0 to 1956998
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Date            393567 non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]
Architecture    393567 non-null object
OS              393567 non-null object
Office          393567 non-null object
price           393567 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), float64(1), object(3)
```

Скорее всего есть решение в 1 строку. Писать функцию, которая резала бы дату, не нужно. Такое отображение необходимо для построения графика. Хочется узнать у опытных дата-сатанистов - какое простое решение имеется?

Comment: Кстати, вы что-то не то передаёте в параметр `parse_dates=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Series.dt.floor("D")](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), чтобы убрать компонент времени из столбца типа `datetime64`:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.floor("D")
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Воспользовался, на выходе получил дату такого вида - 2017-03-30 00:00:00+00:00.  Есть ли возможность избавится от нулей, чтобы дата в итоге имела вид только yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: @СвязнойСвязной, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа [отметьте ответ как решение и/или проголосуйте за ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)